# Coded UI error: The following element is not longer availabe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I recorded some test cases with CUIT in VS2010. Everything worked fine the day before. So, today I run again, all the test failed, with the warning: The following element is no longer available ... and I got the exception : Can't perform "Click" on the hidden control, which is not true because all the controls are not hidden. I tried on the other machine, and they failed as well.

Does anyone know why it happens? Is it because of the web application for something else? Please help, thanks.

PS: So I tried to record a new test with the same controls that said "hidden controls", and the new test worked!? I don't understand why.

**EDIT**

The warning "The following element blah blah ..." appears when I tried to capture an element or a control while recording. The source code of the button is said 'hidden'

```
public HtmlImage UIAbmeldenImage
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIAbmeldenImage == null))
            {
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage = new HtmlImage(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.SearchProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.SearchProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.SearchProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Alt] = "abmelden";
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = "/webakte-vnext/content/apps/Ordner/images/logOut.png";
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Src] = "http://localhost/webakte-vnext/content/apps/Ordner/images/logOut.png";
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.LinkAbsolutePath] = "/webakte-vnext/e.consult.9999/webakte/logout/index";
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Href] = "http://localhost/webakte-vnext/e.consult.9999/webakte/logout/index";
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Class] = null;
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "alt=\"abmelden\" src=\"http://localhost/web";
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "1";
                this.mUIAbmeldenImage.WindowTitles.Add("Akte - Test Akte Coded UI VS2010");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUIAbmeldenImage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I am running Visual Studio 2012, I find it odd that we started experiencing the same problem on the same day, I can not see any difference in the DOM for the Coded UI Tests I have for my web page, but for some reason VS is saying the control is hidden and specifies the correct ID of the element it is looking for (I verified that the ID is still the same one).  I even tried to re-record the action, because I assumed that something must have changed, but I get the same error.

Since this sounds like the same problem, occurring at the same time I am thinking this might be related to some automatic update?  That's my best guess at the moment, I am going to look into it, I will update my post if I figure anything out.

**EDIT**

I removed update KB2870699, which removes some voulnerability in IE, this fixed the problems I was having with my tests.  This update was added on the 12. september, so it fits.  Hope this helps you. :)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800953/security-update-kb2870699-for-ie-breaks-existing-coded-ui-tests#tabs

Comment: The Microsoft forums have a discussion suggesting that KB2870699 is causing problems with Coded UI. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bce4b7dd-9c67-426c-b3f7-472ce6e4d36a/kb2870699-cum-sec-update-for-ie9-windows-7-breaks-coded-ui-tests

Comment: Yes, I also filed a bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800953/security-update-kb2870699-for-ie-breaks-existing-coded-ui-tests#tabs

Comment: @Friðrik, yeah, I happened to know it's a bug from update package since last 2 days, so nothing wrong with my test, I guess :). I also did remove all the updates on 12th, September, and it worked. But I hope Microsoft is gonna fix this problem soon.

Answer (score 3):

Official link to get around the problem :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx

Comment: Most of the information in this shared link are a little outdated, however, it did point to updating VS2012 to Update 4.  This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more serious than that! In my case I can't even record new Coded UI Tests. After I click in any Hyper Link of any web page of my application the coded UI test builder cannot record that click "The following element is no longer available....".

Apparently removing the updates, as said by AdrianHHH do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a field in the `SearchProperties` (or possible the `FilterProperties`) that has a value set by the web site, or that represents some kind of window ID on your desktop. Another possibility is that the web page title changes from day to day or visit to visit. Different executions of the browser or different visits to the web page(s) create different values. Removing these values from the `SearchProperties` (or `FilterProperties`) or changing the check for the title from an `equals` to a `contains` for a constant part of the title should fix the problem. Coded UI often searches for more values than the minimum set needed.

Compare the search properties etc for the same control in the two recorded tests.

**Update based extra detail given in the comments:**

I solved a similar problem as follows. I copied property code similar to that shown in your question into a method that called `FindMatchingControls`. I checked how many controls were returned, in my case up to 3. I examined various properties of the controls found, by writing lots of text to a debug file. In my case I found that the `Left` and `Top` properties were negative for the unwanted, ie hidden, controls.

For your code rather than just using the `UIAbmeldenImage` property, you might call the method below. Change an expression such as

```
HtmlImage im = UIMap.abc.def.UIAbmeldenImage;
```

to be

```
HtmlImage im = FindHtmlHyperLink(UIMap.abc.def);
```

Where the method is:

```
public HtmlImage FindHtmlHyperLink(HtmlDocument doc)
{
    HtmlImage myImage = new HtmlImage(doc);
    myImage.SearchProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
    myImage.SearchProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
    myImage.SearchProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Alt] = "abmelden";
    myImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.AbsolutePath] = "/webakte-vnext/content/apps/Ordner/images/logOut.png";
    myImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Src] = "http://localhost/webakte-vnext/content/apps/Ordner/images/logOut.png";
    myImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.LinkAbsolutePath] = "/webakte-vnext/e.consult.9999/webakte/logout/index";
    myImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Href] = "http://localhost/webakte-vnext/e.consult.9999/webakte/logout/index";
    myImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Class] = null;
    myImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "alt=\"abmelden\" src=\"http://localhost/web";
    myImage.FilterProperties[HtmlImage.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "1";
    myImage.WindowTitles.Add("Akte - Test Akte Coded UI VS2010");

    UITestControlCollection controls = myImage.FindMatchingControls();


    if (controls.Count > 1)
    {
        foreach (UITestControl con in controls)
        {
            if ( con.Left < 0 || con.Top < 0 )
            {
                // Not on display, ignore it.
            }
            else
            {
                // Select this one and break out of the loop.
                myImage = con as HtmlImage;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return myImage;
}
```

Note that the above code has not been compiled or tested, it should be taken as ideas not as the final code.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I looked for the SearchProperties and FilterProperties as you suggested, but it seems correct. I tried to edit something there, but still didn't work. I edited my post, can you have a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @QuiTran Have you tried logging out and back in between tests? Have you tried rebooting between tests? I ask because it is possible the UI controls for an earlier execution are still present, but they are hidden. The search operations then finds the old versions not the new versions that are actually on display.

Comment: Thanks, ah yeah, there's test cases needed to log in under one account, and then log out and log in under another account to test the relationship between 2 accounts. So I guess from your answer, during the recording, I switched on 2 accounts so it caused the problem. So what I should do to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: @QuiTran Added a possible solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Shut down VS2010, launch it again "Run as administrator".

Comment: Thanks, but my VS2010 always runs as administrator, so it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on VS 2012. As a workaround, you can remove that step, and re-record it again. That usually works.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest problem while analyzing the Coded UI test failures is that the error stack trace indicates the line of code which might be completely unrelated to the actual cause of failure.

I would suggest you to enable HTML logging in your tests - this will display step by step details of how Coded UI tried to execute the tests - with screenshots of your application. It will also highlight the control in red which Coded UI is trying to search/operate upon.This is very beneficial in troubleshooting the actual cause of test failures.

To enable tracing you can just add the below code to your app.config file --

[image]