# Failed to perform action on hidden control exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, testing, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to create a UI test in VS 2010 using IE 9 in IE 8 compatibilty mode however when trying to record an action recording many of the steps fail. Then when I manually code in the missing steps and try to fill in a log in form with a username and password I get an exception that says I have failed to perform an action on hidden control.

The UI Test code:

```
public void Recordedmethod()
{
        BrowserWindow uILogInWindowsInternetWindow = this.UILogInWindowsInternetWindow;
        HtmlHyperlink uILogInHyperlink = this.UILogInWindowsInternetWindow.UIHomePageDocument.UILogInHyperlink;
        HtmlEdit uIUsernameEdit = this.UILogInWindowsInternetWindow.UILogInDocument1.UIUsernameEdit;
        HtmlEdit uIPasswordEdit = this.UILogInWindowsInternetWindow.UILogInDocument1.UIPasswordEdit;
        #endregion

        // Go to web page 'http://localhost:15856/WebSite1/'
        uILogInWindowsInternetWindow.NavigateToUrl(new System.Uri(this.RecordedMethodParams.UILogInWindowsInternetWindowUrl));

        // Set flag to allow play back to continue if non-essential actions fail. (For example, if a mouse hover action fails.)
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

        // Mouse hover 'Log In' link at (1, 1)
        Mouse.Click(uILogInHyperlink);

        // Reset flag to ensure that play back stops if there is an error.
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = false;

        // Type 'test' in 'Username:' text box
        uIUsernameEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethodParams.UIUsernameEditText;

        // The following element is no longer available: IE web control; Process Id [6320], window handle [3168166]

        // Type '********' in 'Password:' text box
        uIPasswordEdit.Password = this.RecordedMethodParams.UIPasswordEditPassword;

        // The following element is no longer available: IE web control; Process Id [6320], window handle [3168166]
}
```

Comment: Could this security patch bug be the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900119/cannot-perform-click-on-the-hidden-control-visual-studio-2012-only

Comment: @yonitdm that is for VS 2012 not VS 2010

Comment: @yonitdm apparently this is not just a 2012 issue, thanks for the link, add it as the answer and I will vote you up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coded UI error: The following element is not longer availabe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764709/coded-ui-error-the-following-element-is-not-longer-availabe)

Comment: too slow :P Glad you found the problem. We are having difficulty getting our update services to stop re-pushing this update after we remove it. I hope there is a better solution soon!

Comment: @yonitdm we have the same issue at work, thankfully we haven't begun using this tool for testing and are just researching it. Hopefully they patch it soon, otherwise I guess an upgrade to VS 2012 will have to do.

Comment: I just did a clean install of IE9 on April 11 and I am having this problem. Since there is no security update to uninstall and I have VS2010, I think I am just SOL. Might be time to switch to an open source alternative.

Comment: There was a patch put out to fix the issue in VS 2010, have you tried applying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue linked to an Internet Explorer patch that was released in September.

**KB2870699**

This affects VS2010 and VS2012.

Microsoft released a patch that corrects the issue for VS2012 (and I've confirmed that it fixed the issue for me).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx

Currently the only workaround for VS2010 is to uninstall the patch (KB2870699); however, as with any sort of security patch you'll want to consider carefully whether pulling it is safe to do given your situation.

EDIT: This was not a fun bug for me to deal with. I had just upgraded to VS2012 from VS2010 and all of a sudden I found none of my previously functioning CodedUI tests working. I assumed it was an issue with VS2012 and after banging my head against the wall for the better part of a day I found out it was an issue with a patch. It was just my luck that I upgraded to 2012 at the same time the patch had been installed on my system. Good times!

Comment: yeh its a real pain to deal with, at first I thought it was an issue with the auto-code generation, so I tried for hours to manually code and it still kept failing lol

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an updated for VS 2012 to fix this issue

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: also that link has been posted

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my coded ui test. It's an issue with **VS-2012** i guess, i tried every update (installing/uninstalling them and everything..) nothing worked. 
I tried **VS-2013 Ultimate** and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

You can use exception handling to capture the error while still not having the test failed.

The test is failing because at the time it performs click action, the control is hidden.

```
try 
{
   //your code goes here
}
catch(FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```