# Coded UI - Unable to find menu items

Tags: c#, firefox, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10, coded-ui-tests

I've been tasked with getting to know Visual Studio's Coded UI testing "utility" as well as teaching myself C# for automation purposes. We run a web based program, and I'm having great difficulty with menu items and screens. I generate a new script to:
1. Log into application
2. Browse the menu and select an account
I cant seem to get past the log in screen, I can get it to put the username part in, but the test fails (error below) when I want it to add the password. Same sort of issue when attempting to click on menus items. We have ascertained that many of the menu items look like the image down below when I use the bulls-eye to help identify the menu item:
[image]

Between Firefox, Chrome and IE (oh my....IE is bad), they behave differently. My C# knowledge is VERY limited and I simply can't make it work. Any input would be appreciated!

*ERROR:*

> {"Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value \"User1\"' on the
>   control. Additional Details: \r\nTechnologyName: 'MSAA'\r\nName:
>   'Please enter your username, password and PIN; and then click the
>   Login button. If you are not registered and require information about
>   the service please contact us for further information.
>   '\r\nControlType: 'Edit'\r\n"}

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Unless you've installed Selenium components for cross browser testing, you're not going to have any sort of success testing with Chrome or Firefox. You'll want to test in IE. ---- okay so it looks like you're using Firefox. Run your test in Internet Explorer instead or install the following before testing in firefox/chrome: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d

Comment: I have run the test on IE (10). I get a little further, but I get the same problem somewhere else in a menu. I though IE will at least be perfect, but it's just as messed up.

Comment: can you post the error you're getting when you test with IE10? It's possible it's something else that's going wrong this time around.

Comment: **{"Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control. Additional Details: \r\nTechnologyName:  'Web'\r\nControlType:  'Hyperlink'\r\nId:  ''\r\nName:  ''\r\nTagName:  'A'\r\nTarget:  ''\r\nInnerText:  'Account'\r\n"}**

Comment: This sounds like it might be related to a bug in VS2010 and VS2012.  Check here for more info - you might be able to fix this issue with an update to VS2012.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442361/failed-to-perform-action-on-hidden-control-exception/19496938#19496938

Comment: Thanks for that. it looks like this Coded UI thing is going to be a nightmare...

Comment: My Visual Studio is now fully updated but it's still fragile as anything.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI is all about successfully identifying the objects you want to interact with.  You can either code those objects directly in the 2nd half of the .uitest file, or change the search properties of the recorded/auto generated objects by right clicking on the object from the map view and changing the SearchProperties property collection.  This will change the code for the .designer.cs file for you.  You can find lots of examples of this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balagans/archive/2009/12/28/9941582.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398062.aspx).  My guess is that the recording has the specified objects too strongly identified (often times is uses inner text values or other values that could be dynamically set at run time, meaning the test runner has trouble finding it the second time around).

Regarding the password entry, a lot of times you need to enter the value as an encrypted text.  You can either set `object.Password` or `object.Text`.  If you set `object.Password` and the string you're entering is unencrypted, you'll need to `Playback.EncryptText(unencryptedString)`.  Otherwise, you should be able to just set the value of the text to that string.