# How To identify Object After Navigation in Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

i m new to MS Coded UI Automating, my Question is.
  When i launch my Browser (IE) and fill the detials and then click on submit button. it takes me to new page where i get an error called action cannot be perform on hidden objects

i am using MS 2012 Premium Verison

thanks

Comment: What is the action you are attempting on the next page? What does the code look like? Do you have all of the updates for VS2012 installed? These and other questions will help us help you.

Comment: using coded ui test builder i m able to highligth the object on first page but as soon as i go on next page and try to spy the object nothing happens. i m just able to spy the url and nothing else on that page so, is there any way that we can update the object..

Comment: So you see the object on the second page, but the spy doesn't see any properties? If you open the properties of the object in the UIMap, you can edit it to make it more generic in case the properties differ slightly based on the URL for example, but you'd need to be able to access it on the 2nd page.

Comment: No, on second page it does not identify the object with spy or any other method. The problem is when i add all the objects on first page and click on submit button it takes me to second page and there it does not identify the page or any objects so, in that case when i close my UI Test Builder and again open it then it identifies the objects on second page but while running the flow it give me error on second page that "hidden objects cannot be performed action"

Answer (score 0):

Limited information to go on, but have you checked out this the fallowing?

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx
- [Coded UI error: The following element is not longer availabe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764709/coded-ui-error-the-following-element-is-not-longer-availabe/18829142#18829142)

This might be the annoying side effect of Windows Update KB2870699, update 4 for VS2012 is supposed to fix this but an alternative work around is simply to uninstall this update.